# Racket, ragg: doesn't accept token stream

Tags: parsing, token, racket

Using `#lang ragg` in Racket to create a parser for a simple language. Here is the grammar:

```
#lang ragg
program : sexpr* start* layout
sexpr   : SEXPR

start   : WORD WORD "[" WORD* "=" ">" sexpr "]"

layout  : elem*
elem    : info | text | sexpr
info    : "{" text "}"
text    : WORD*
```

And here are the first few tokens:

```
#(struct:token-struct SEXPR (define a 'something) #f 1 0 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct WORD run #f 1 22 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct WORD ram-loop #f 1 26 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct [ [ #f 1 35 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct WORD ram #f 1 36 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct WORD max-ram #f 1 40 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct = = #f 1 48 #f #f)
#(struct:token-struct > > #f 1 49 #f #f)
```

(edit) And the input text is: `(define a 'something) run ram-loop [ram max-ram => (format \"~a/~a GB RAM\" ram max-ram)] {ram} {fg:#966} {cpu} Some text (leftsep #363)`

(edit) And of course.. the error I get when calling `(parse)` on the token stream:

```
; Encountered unexpected token #\[ ("[") while parsing #f [line=1, column=35,
;   offset=#f] [,bt for context]
```

It seems obvious that `SEXPR WORD WORD [` should be accepted by the grammar. Any idea why it is not?

Comment: Accompanying reader, and `parser-tester.rkt` which is what I run to get these results: https://github.com/Ploppz/bar_dsl/tree/master/bar